# Weird big triangles appear when I select an object

Tags: interface, error

I am having some default,I guess, problem with some weird triangles appear while I'm moving an object.That also happens even when I am choosing the object.

This is what it looks like before I choose the cube:

[image]

This is what it looks like after:

[image]

Comment: Very likely a gpu issue, what is your gpu? Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: It looks like an error related to the GPU. Are you using one that is supported by blender https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware

Comment: As i recall is an i7 dell,something like that.I believe it's either that or the OS isn't exactly compatible.I have parrot OS